# Create dynamically HTML file (Client - Side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is relativelly simple. I need to construct a script in javascript / jquery if possible which will construct HTML files dynamically. I've read that apparently it's not possible to access to the client system file but aren't they solutions ?

Comment: Going to have to be a bit more clear here.

Comment: The browser does not have access to save files to the user's hard drive nor to the server's hard drive. You could send the HTML text to the server and write a page that saves it there.

Comment: It's not possible to access the client file system without using a proprietary browser plugin of some sort.

Comment: Lot's of people talk about ActiveX, is there a ActiveX like for Chrome ?

Comment: If you have to ask, you don't want to build an ActiveX plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find `$.tmpl` useful. [Check this out.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

Answer (score 0):

The Browser will not have access to save files to the users local drive; however, you can certainly user jQuery to generate HTML and render it to the current browser window.

Comment: But you mean that it will be a temp files ?

Comment: No, it will not be a "file" at all, but jQuery can be used to modify the contents of the DOM, which you can use to write your own HTML, giving the appearance of changing the current screen on the fly.